# Joda Time Output Depending on JDK

Tags: jodatime

I am running the following code that uses Joda Time. The "getShortName" function is somehow retrieving the results from the JDK database.
I've tested this with JDK 8.91, and 7, and the output is different.
**I thought Joda uses it's own Database compiled in the JAR?**
**How I can I use the latest Databse in the  Joda Jar instead of depending on the JDK?**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
          DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Metlakatla");        
          DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.mediumDateTime();

          format=format.withZone(zone);

          long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
          {
              long next = zone.nextTransition(current);
              if (current == next)
              {
                  break;
              }
              System.out.println (format.print(next) + " Into DST? " 
                                  + !zone.isStandardOffset(next)+" "+zone.getShortName(next));
              current = next;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Joda-Time does manage its own time zone rules but not its own time zone names. You have to make a difference between rules and names. Latter one is only found in JDK-resources.

Comment: I am looking at the source code, and at least the abbreviations are in the TZ database, and Joda indeed has them.  It seems silly to show "PST" when it knows that it's "AKDT" just because the JDK is not up do date. When it comes to abbreviations like PST, is there really a Locale that  displays PST in another way?  I am looking for a way to get Joda to just output it in the words that are in the TZ database.

Comment: And if Joda doesn't work that way, isn't it quite strange to follow the correct rules, but display the incorrect names(if JDK is older)?.. It would totally mess up the output, saying that this is PST time when in fact it's AKDT time.

Comment: No, the time zone names and abbreviations of JDK are NOT based on what the TZ database says. Instead the JDK uses CLDR-data as origin but compile it into its own localized resource format. And Joda-Time just delegates to what the JDK says. The only thing of TZ database which is adopted are the rules. Be aware that most TZDB abbreviations are just invented or guessed and will possibly replaced by an offset format for many zones in the future (Asia/Tomsk seems to be an actual example for this tendency).

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I tried the tzupdater for the JDK and it still didn't fix the naming.  Is there any way to update the naming data in the JDK then?.. Or how would you go about having the most up to date abbreviations?

Comment: Good question. I am not aware of any published alternative tz name repository (myself, I am planning to do such a thing however). ICU4J might be such an alternative source (with more data than JDK) else the official interface for such data is implementing a [SPI-provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/TimeZoneNameProvider.html). Maybe you could start such an implementation based on `java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName(...)` and override it for the zones you are interested in. And of course, installing a newer JDK-version (not the same as TZ-updater), might also help.

Comment: Great info, thanks a lot!.. I think there are multiple answers to this question in here, although not Joda related, but it answers what I was trying to do.

Comment: I just gave ICU4j a try, and it seems it's missing the time zone abbreviations.  It has about 20 of them, but some like EEST/EEDT are missing, it just shows GMT+2 and GMT+3.. Unfortunately it seems it has less data than JDK.